# This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening

Tags: this, edit

This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but this question is highly off-topic. See: [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: google your question. You will find many answering blogs for your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, just do it, you don't have to "look" for anything just make apps, make better and better apps, start with a simple MySql login app, then manipulate data from database make a forms app that displays something, make a simple text editor etc etc and put it on Github, so you can show it on a interview simple as that.

Good luck!

Comment: @andreycruz16 dunno, Im new here also :D

Comment: Great answer. I am changing fields and was wondering how to go about becoming a developer but this is really great advice. Are there any community driven events like competitions and group challenges for programming?